# how do i refresh the div after a click function using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

im trying to refresh a div on the page using jquery after a click function:

```
$('.finishTag').live('click', function() {
           $('#Qtopics').hide();
            //refresh #hiddenTopic here im stuck here :))
           $('#hiddenTopic').show();

            });
```

EDIT:

i mean refresh the div once!! and then show it because its hidden at this point!!!

```
<div id="hiddentTopic">
 <?php

       while ($Qtopic = mysql_fetch_array($getTopics)){
         echo "<a href='google.com' class='topicBullet'>".$Qtopic['name']."</a>";
             }
?>
       </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by refresh? put some data?

Comment: edited answer im just trying to refresh the content!!! on #hiddentTopic

Comment: `$('#hiddenTopic').text("Edited content");` or html()

Comment: After you edit post - You want to rerun php part by javascript? :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right, you wanna reload content, generated by php part. It's impossible because php is a server-side part while javascript - client-side. What you neeed is to make file `server.php`, move php part there and then use `$('#hiddenTopic').load("server.php");` As @gowri said before.

Comment: can i ask if i wanted to pass a parameter to server.php like the comment_id so it knows what to access, how can i do that with.load()

Comment: Simply `$('#hiddenTopic').load("server.php?comment_id=" + comment_id );`

Answer (score 1):

use `load`

```
$('#hiddenTopic').load("server.php");
```

check your id  that is with t

```
hiddentTopic
```

please change it

```
hiddenTopic
```

like this

working demo

http://jsfiddle.net/JLyay/1/

and this is not a refresh this is called `hide and show`

Comment: what deos server.php come from!! :))

Comment: hiddenTopic div already has content inside it that access the database in php, i just need refresh it!! :)) thanks

Comment: @pingpong then what you want to refresh?

Comment: why need to refresh it .. which means you need to show latest content right . then just echo your latest content from server.php

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to change the formating of div you can do that using any css class like this: $('divId').addClass('class_name');

to add data you can pick the div using divid and update its innet paragraph aur heading text like this:

$('div1 p').html('**blah blah** any text … ');
$('h2').text('**blah blah** blah blah …');

$('**START!**').prependTo('#divID'); (it write START before div)
$('**END!**').appendTo('#divID'); (it write END after div)

hope this ll help you.